# Django: how to hook django commands with additional options

Tags: django

Django commands allows to optional settings by passing `--settings=custom.py`

How do I go about adding an extra option like `--business=b1` so I can initialise business specific stuff for **all existing commands, without having to modify all of them**?

eg.

```
./manage.py process_orders --business=b1
```

I might have to monkey patch `BaseCommand` and `handle_default_options`

Comment: how about creating a super class with shared functionality for all your custom commands?

Comment: Hi, no sorry, I knew about this approach and it's not as practical as you thought, I am writing a library and installed to all projects, it's not as easy to change existing code.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty well explained in the docs[1]. The following is an example from the docs, but slightly modified to include business option.

```
from optparse import make_option

class Command(BaseCommand):
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--business',
            dest='business',
            default=None,
            help='business help text'),
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # ...
        if options['business']:
            print 'found'
        # ...
```

This will add the `--business` option to the existing Django options.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Can you point to very exactly in the docs it states how to add options to *all* commands? Couldn't find it.

Comment: it's inferred, if you can do it to one command and then use that as your new command then it can be applied to all.

Comment: I didn't see the `all existing commands` before. There best way to do what you want is to make a single base command with the options you want in it, then inherit that class instead of `BaseCommand` for all your management commands.

Comment: well thanks for the answer, but I knew about this approach already, I don't want to modify the existing commands, since I am writing a library and deployed to all projects, it's not as easy as to "change" all command codes.